# How Can I Simplify This Logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How can I simplify $\log_7 49^x$ ?

I realise that an online calculator can give me the answers, but I needed to learn the steps to arrive at the answer. I have now understood it - thank you.

As I don't have access to anybody in real life to assist me, the wonderful community here on this website is my only go to place for help.

I have realised too late in life that math is beautiful and am learning it all over again for the sake of wanting to love maths.

As stated before, the support and help I receive here is much appreciated and will continue to motivate me.

Comment: (-1): as it stands, you could literally type this into an online calculator and get an answer.

Comment: I am still learning and wanted to know the steps to reach the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, but it is expected here that you give at least some indication of your own thoughts and efforts on the problem. This is why you've had two questions closed as off-topic (soon to be a third...) and why this has been so heavily downvoted.

Comment: Yes, I'm still learning about down-votes and my own thoughts and efforts on the problem -I'm getting there. I'm about as inexperienced as they get. I will be making more efforts to contribute my thoughts in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt... figure out what it means...

$\log_7 49^x = k$ means

$7^k = 49^x$

If you put $49$ to base $7$ that is $49^x = (7^2)^x = 7^{2x}$ so $k = 2x$.

Once you get comfortable with this you can have faith in "the rules".

$\log_b c^d = d\log_b c$ and $\log_b b^k = k$ so $\log_7 49^x = x\log_7 49=x\log_7 7^2 = x*2 = 2x$.

Comment: That has made it very clear. Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_7 49^x=x\log_7 49 =x\log_7 7^2$$
$$=2x\log_7 7 = 2x\cdot 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\log_7 49^x=x\log_7 49=2x$$

or as an alternative

$$\log_7 49^x=\log_7 7^{2x}=2x \log_7 7=2x$$

We have used that

$$\log_a b^c=c\log_a b$$